# unitary operator between two Hilbert subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

$H$ is a Hilbert space. $P, Q$ are projections.
For every $x\in P(H)$, we have decomposition $x =  Qx +Q^\perp x$. Then, can we find a unitary operator from the space generated by all $Qx$, $x\in P(H)$, to a subspace of $P(H)$? If we can, what is the form of this unitary operator.

Comment: so $x \in H$, and $P(H)$ is a subspace of $H$. and $Qx$ is a 1-dimensional subspace of $H$. so you are asking about an unitary operator from a 1-dimensional subspace to another ???

Comment: or you meant an unitary operator from $Q(P(H))$ to a subspace of $P(H)$, and in that case the identity operator works (again).

Comment: Are your projections intended to be orthogonal projections, or a general projection. And what is $Q^{\perp}$?

Comment: @user1952009 Yep， that is what I mean. But the space is for all $x\in P(H)$

Comment: @TrialAndError  $Q^\perp$ is the $I - Q$, the complement. $P, Q$ are not necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: Are you looking for a unitary with some particular special properties?  For there to be a unitary operator between two Hilbert spaces, they just have to have the same dimension...

Answer (score 0):

Let $E\subseteq H$ be the closure of $Q(P(H))$.  Then $Q$ is a bounded linear map from $P(H)$ to $E$ with dense image, and it follows that $\dim E\leq \dim P(H)$ (if $P(H)$ is finite-dimensional this is just linear algebra; if $P(H)$ is infinite-dimensional, note that its dimension is the same as the minimal cardinality of a dense subset, and then the image of that subset is dense in $E$).  Thus $E$ is isometric to a closed subspace of $P(H)$.  If you are asking about the set $Q(P(H))$ rather than its closure, then it is also isometric to a subspace of $P(H)$ by just restricting any isometry on $E$.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a unitary operator in von Neumann algebra.    I think you can help me.   That is, let $P, Q$ be a projection in a vNa(semifinite with a semifinite faithful noraml tace $\tau$). If $\tau(P) < \tau(Q)$, I believe that $Q\wedge P^\perp >0$(I also can prove the case for finite dimensional $B(H)$).    If the projection $R$ corresponding to $QP(H)$ has a trace $ \tau(R) <\tau(Q)$ and there is a unitary operator $U$ such that $R = UPU^*$, then the assertation is true.  But I am not sure whether  $U$  belongs to the vNA  and how to show $\tau(R) <\tau(Q)$.